# Force method to accept different variables in signature

Tags: c#, methods, multidimensional-array, signature

is there a way to force a method in c# to accept arrays/variables of different types in the same signature slot or to make it ignore one part of the signature?

My code:

```
       private void array_joiner(String[,] newArray, Int32[,] MatrixArray, String[,] RekursionArray, Char[] ArrayX, Char[] ArrayY)
    {
        for (Int16 i = 0; i < ArrayX.Length + 1; i++)
        {
            newArray[i, 0] = ArrayX[i].ToString();
        }
        for (Int16 i = 1; i < ArrayY.Length + 1; i++)
        {
            newArray[0, i] = ArrayY[i].ToString();
        }

        for (Int16 y = 1; y < ArrayY.Length + 1; y++)
        {
            for (Int16 x = 1;  x < ArrayX.Length +1; x++)
            {
                newArray[y, x] = MatrixArray[y, x].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

My problem is basically that I want to parse two different arrays in the slot of Int32[,]MatrixArray (Int32[,] and String[,]) to the method but I just don't know how. Anyone got a better idea than to write two different methods? Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could just declare them as the Array class and then work out the type of the data in the arrays and how many ranks they have separately.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have two ways:

- Make it a generics method http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/512aeb7t.aspx (being careful to handle multidimensional collections which could be tricky)
- Overload the method, declaring two signatures with the same name and different parameters http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229029(v=vs.100).aspx